# Hibernate: Mapping with one-to-many on non-primary-key columns

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm stuck at the hibernate xml mapping configuration.

I've established some tables with foreign key constraints in my MSSQL database:

```
Table ItemsBase 
ID       int   primary-key
ItemID   int   unique index
... some more columns

Table Others
ID       int   primary-key
ItemID   int   unique index
... some more columns
```

The foreign key constraint is configured to connect these two tables by using the column "ItemID".

My ItemsBase.hbm.xml files looks like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.delife.sql.ItemsBase" table="ItemsBase" schema="dbo" catalog="Delife_Plenty">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id> 
        <property name="itemId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ItemID" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="otherses" table="Others" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key property-ref="itemId">
                <column name="ItemID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="de.delife.sql.Others" not-found="ignore" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the Others.hbm.xml files looks like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="de.delife.sql.Others" table="Others" schema="dbo" catalog="Delife_Plenty">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="itemsBase" class="de.delife.sql.ItemsBase" fetch="select" property-ref="itemId">
            <column name="ItemID" unique="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Everything looks fine for me, but when I run my program I get a hibernate error:

```
property [itemId] not found on entity [de.delife.sql.Others]
```

I have an established relation between ItemsBase and a table named ItemsProperties and it works, but with this "pretty" table "Others" I'm stuck.

I would be glad, if someone can help me on this matter. Thx in advance.

Comment: can you share your `Others` entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item id should be defined as a property in Others.hbm.xml:

```
<property name="itemId" column="ItemId"/>
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation, but I get the same error message... Despite this: In my class ItemProperties it works with property-ref="itemId"...

Comment: Looks like it is because you need to tell hibernate about the itemId property. I've corrected my answer, could you check?

Comment: I guess you're right. It seems to work. I don't understand hibernate in this point. I tried this with another hibernate class yesterday and I got an "duplicate mapping" error. But in this case it's working.... aaaaaah

Comment: On another relationship I tried to implement your idea and I get a "repeated column in mapping for entity: xxx" error. Why???

Comment: As the error suggests, there are multiple definitions of the same property xxx

Comment: But there aren't multiple definitions:

        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="itemsBase" class="de.delife.sql.ItemsBase" fetch="select" property-ref="itemId">
            <column name="ItemID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="itemId" column="ItemID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property name="intValue" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="intValue" />
        </property>

Comment: If you could post the hbm as a separate SO question, we could definitely take a look.

Comment: I created a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632605/repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-where-each-column-is-only-mapped-once)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this. I tried and its working for me.

```
<set name="otherses" table="Others"  inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="itemId" foreign-key="itemId" property-ref="itemId"/>
    <one-to-many class="de.delife.sql.Others" not-found="ignore" />
</set>
```