# "Repeated column in mapping for entity" where each column is only mapped once

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate mapping file ParcelServicePresetIds.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="de.delife.sql.ParcelServicePresetIds" table="ParcelServicePresetIDs" schema="dbo" catalog="xxx">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="itemsBase" class="de.sql.ItemsBase" fetch="select" property-ref="itemId">
        <column name="ItemID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="itemId" column="ItemID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <property name="intValue" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="intValue" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I run my program I get an error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: de.sql.ParcelServicePresetIds column: ItemID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Why?

I've another entity Others.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="itemsBase" class="de.sql.ItemsBase" fetch="select" property-ref="itemId">
    <column name="ItemID" unique="true" />
</many-to-one>
<property name="itemId" column="ItemID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

In this entity it's working!!! I do not understand it!
Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `ItemID` columns twice: one time with `<property />` and second time with `<many-to-one />` tag.
Remove one (probably `<property/>` declaration)

Comment: I started without having ItemID defined as a separate property and I got another failure (no property...). So I inserted the property statement...

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use a propertyRef here. It could simply be:

```
<many-to-one name="itemsBase" class="de.sql.ItemsBase" fetch="select" column="ItemID"/>
```

Also, you don't require the property declaration for `itemId`.

To answer the second part of the question:

- Whenever you give propertyRef, you need to follow it up with a property definition.
- If it is a 'managed column', i.e. a foreign-key-reference for example; you ought to qualify the property definition with  `insert="false" update="false"`
- However, in most cases; you donot need a propertyRef. You can do with a simple column definition in the many-to-one section.

Comment: I've answered the follow-up question

Comment: In Other.hbm.xml I need the property declaration, but in ParcelServicePresetIds.hbm.xml I don't need it... Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: @user1737686 No mention!